# Problems with Parallax being jittery in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

...I'm working with some Parallax code I found on the internet and it seems to work for all browsers on a Mac (Safari, Opera, Chrome, Firefox). But it doesn't work as expected in Chrome on a PC - it is choppy when you scroll through it (using the mouse wheel). I can't figure out how to fix this and what I have found online nothing seems to help. I'm pasting all my code associated with the Parallax effect. Note that things like text and source I'm putting "..." to maintain privacy and confidentiality.

First Parallax HTML

```
    <div class="row bgParallax" id="home1" data-speed="4"><img class="img-responsive" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" src=“..." alt="" width="464" height="295" />
 <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="panel-heading">
   <h2 class="text-center”>...</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <p style="margin-top: 20px;”>...</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
  <p class="textDown”>...</p>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"><!-- Down Arrow --></span></div>
</div>
```

Second Parallax HTML

```
    <div id="home2" class="row bgParallax" data-speed="6">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 25px!important;">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src=“..." width="100%" height="150" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 25px!important;">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src=“..." width="100%" height="150" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .bgParallax { 
position: relative;  
background-position: 50% 0; background-repeat: repeat; 
background-attachment: fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-attachment: fixed;
-moz-background-attachment: fixed;
-o-background-attachment: fixed;
-ms-background-attachment: fixed;
}

.bg-1 {
background: url('....jpg') 50% 0 fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
     height: 1000px;
    position: relative; 
    padding: 100px 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-attachment: fixed;
-moz-background-attachment: fixed;
-o-background-attachment: fixed;
-ms-background-attachment: fixed;
}
.bg-2 { 
background: url('...') 50% 0 fixed; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
     height: 800px;
    position: relative; 
    padding: 150px 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

JS

```
$('div.bgParallax').each(function(){
  var $obj = $(this);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $obj.data('speed'));
    var bgpos = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
    $obj.css('background-position', bgpos );
  });
});
```

Website Link: http://peaceandplentyinn.mybnbwebsite.com/

Comment: Are you sure it's just not that the mouse wheel on PC skips xlines in chrome and doesn't accelerate and decelerate. It works fine on my PC on chrome if I use the mouse wheel button, then moving down, while choppy if I scroll using the mouse wheel.

Comment: So its not necessarily an issue with Chrome? Is there something that can be done to fix the scroll wheel?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chrome+smooth+scrolling&oq=chrome+smooth+scrolling&aqs=chrome..69i57.3111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8